# How to enable the ghost effect on a table row in Safari HTML5?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, draggable

I don't have the ghost effect when I drag item (`table` row) on Safari. 
I use `table` so this is a `tr`. The ghost effect is when you can see your item which follow your mouse.

On Chrome, FF it works.

**Anyone know why?**

I noticed it doesn't only on `tr/td`. If I use `li` or `a`, I can see the ghost effect...

**Chrome**

[image]

**Safari**

[image]

Comment: are you saying that text-shadow doesnt work in chrome if your textshadow is inside a table row?

Comment: im sorry but its still not clear... are you using text shadow for the ghost effect?

Comment: Why do you talking about text-shadow... ?

Comment: Not working on Chrome for Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Safari the drag helper (ghost effect) shows up as soon as you attach drag&drop related event listeners to the table rows.

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1" draggable="true">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With only this, drag helper won't show up.

But as soon as you attach an event, it will:

```
var row1 = document.getElementById('row1');
row1.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    //Dragstart code here
}, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I've just been dealing with this issue myself, and hopefully this might be useful to someone else discovering this question.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432971/468150), there's a bug in Safari when generating the drag ghost for elements with `display: table-row` within a `<table>` (it also appears to apply to `display: table-group`.) That answer suggests changing the `display` property to something else, which does indeed cause a correct drag ghost to be created, although it of course changes the layout in (probably) unwanted ways.

The trick I've found is to change the style in my `onDragStart` handler, and use a timeout to (almost) immediately reset it. I also temporarily hard-code to the row and cell widths to match their current sizes as these are otherwise recalculated. Finally, I explicitly set the drag image to ensure that it's correctly positioned under the mouse pointer. Here's a function which does the trick when passed the drag event:

```js
function hackRowForDragInSafari(event) {
    let row = event.target

    for (let cell of row.cells) {
        cell.style.setProperty('width', cell.offsetWidth + 'px', 'important')
    }

    row.style.setProperty('width', row.offsetWidth + 'px', 'important')
    row.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important')

    setTimeout(() => {
        for (let cell of row.cells) {
            cell.style.removeProperty('width')
        }

        row.style.removeProperty('display')
        row.style.removeProperty('width')
    })

    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)
}
```

Ideally, you'd only trigger this if the UA is Safari, and you'll want to adapt this to your use case if you're using a drag handle in a cell, or if you're already using staying on your table this would break, etc.