# Table TR with background-size bug Safari

Tags: css, background, background-image, css-tables, background-size

Look at this fiddle, he will work different on safari and chrome:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/sew120xt/1/
```

Desired look (chrome):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ABs.png
```

Bugged look (safari):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc6YF.png
```

Seems like Safari will treat the style for TR as a style for his childrens instead, is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be correct that it is a bug. It isn't just the element `<tr>` itself but any element displayed as a `table-row` in a `table` displayed element. I've replicated the issue in the snippet below using non-table elements by changing the `display` property of each. (will only show incorrectly in Safari).

If you are able to change the `display` property of `tr { }` without it affecting your layout/design it will fix it. Try a few of the other [display properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to see if any work.

```css
.tbody {
  background-color:red;
  display: table;
}
.tr {
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, black, black);
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  color:white;
  display: table-row;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbody">
  <div class="tr">
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <span>bbbbbbbbbbbb</span>
    <span>cccccccccccc</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'll try a workaround with this.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've found that changing the `display` property in an `onDragStart` handler and then immediately reverting the change using `setTimeout` will also work. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59050559/468150) to another question for more details.

Comment: What display property would you recommend? I tried all of them and all ruined the layout tragically. 